# Upload image to one of 3 separate ImageViews, after clicking one of 3 buttons

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an activity where you can upload 3 different pictures after clicking one of the 3 different buttons. You can only choose images one by one, as opposed to choosing 3 in one go. Each "button" is actually a `clickable` `ImageView`, which when clicked should prompt the user to choose a picture and then the picture they select should populate the `ImageView` that they clicked. I know how to work with just 1 imageView per activity so I'm currently stuck.

My thought process is as follows:

1. Have 3 different `Boolean` variables which are linked to 3 different `clickable` `ImageViews`.

   ```
    private var clickedView1: Boolean = false
    //same for the other views
   ```
2. When 1 of the views is clicked(`OnClickListeners`), toggle the `Boolean` linked to it so that it's true.

   ```
    upload1.setOnClickListener {
        clickedView1 = true
        uploadPicture()
    }
    //same for the other views
   ```
3. If the boolean updates to true, populate the corresponding imageView (done in the onActivityResult).

   ```
        if (clickedView1) {
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            selectedPhotoUri1 = data.data
            ImagesList?.plus(selectedPhotoUri1)
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri1)
            upload1.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            }
        } else if { 
            //same thing for the other views
        }
   ```

In my head that makes sense, but I know it's wrong and when I program it and launch the activity, I have to be strategic RE the order I populate the image views (i.e. it only works from the last `ImageView`, going to the first). Any other order doesn't work and will always populate the first `ImageView`, no matter which is clicked.

Is there an efficient and accurate way of doing the population + `OnClickListeners`?

Comment: So the problem is that your image always uploads into first ImageView, regardless of which was clicked?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue @alexal1, unless i select from the last one to the first and not in any other order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the solution:** (I can only mark it as correct in 2 days)

Following the explanation that I detailed in the question, the only thing that I did was to update the boolean variable for when an image view is not clicked to `false`, otherwise, whenever you click it once, it keeps the variable as true and I guess this causes the confusion as to which view should be populated.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Android recreates your Activity while you're picking an image. You didn't provide the code of `uploadPicture()` method but I suppose that it opens image picker in another app. So, values of your variables may be lost, including `clickedView1` and others. You can check it by putting a log in `onActivityResult()` which shows values of these variables.

If I'm right then one of possible solutions is to save your variables' values in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore them in `onCreate()` like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    clickedView1 = savedInstanceState?.getBoolean(KEY_CLICKED_VIEW_1)
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    outState?.putBoolean(KEY_CLICKED_VIEW_1, clickedView1)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

For future improvements you can also consider

- Using one `int` instead of three `Boolean`s to remember chosen ImageView
- Using different request codes for different ImageViews when picking an image instead of saving state.

Comment: I have used a log statement and I think I might've found the issue. The boolean variables for the others (i.e. ones that aren't clicked at that time) remain `true`. I have changed this so that when a view is clicked, only the boolean corresponding to it is updated to `true` and the others are updated to `false`. Unfortunately, this is just not working as it now keeps everything as `false`, but I have a feeling that's where the issue is. I did the update in the `SetOnClickListener` by just assigning `false` to the other 2 booleans that correspond to the ones that weren't clicked.

Comment: and you're right about `uploadPicture()`, all it does is bring up the image picker.

Comment: Don't forget to test the case when you rotate the screen while in gallery. It will reset all variables if they are not saved like in the answer.

Comment: my bad, please forget the first comment, it works now(: thanks for the suggestion to use Log statements. I always underestimate their usefulness. I'll add an answer.